# express-session not storing cookies in CORS client domain

Tags: express, express-session

I have tried the suggestions shared in other questions, and I am successfully able to set cookie to client(localhost:3000) from server(localhost:8000), and everything works fine. (See the below code that's working in this scenario).

But, when I try with the client and server as below, express-session does not store cookie on the client side. All GET/POST requests are working correctly though.

Client domain: http://127.0.0.1:3000 (or any other https domain)
Server domain: http://localhost:8000

I have tried all possible options suggested on other questions, but nothing working.
Please correct me, if I am expecting wrong from express-session for CORS domain.

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
//...

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, Authorization, Set-Cookie"
  );
    next();
});


app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,  //mongoDB session store
    domain: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    cookie: {
      domain: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
      // sameSite: "none",
     // secure: true,
     // httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 300 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

//...
//server hosted on localhost:8000
```

Comment: Search for "3rd-party cookies" on StackOverflow.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen could you please add more info? I'm able to find something useful!

Comment: I assume your browser blocks the cookie because it is a third-party cookie (127.0.0.1 <> localhost). There are many similar questions and answers on StackOverflow already.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I looked into the Network tab and I saw the cookies were successfully arriving at the browser, so yes the browser was blocking the cookies. I moved the localhost server to https server and with some changes in `express-session` config, it worked! Thank you for the insights!!!